# Composer some problems

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i have a problem when installing composer, the folders {vendor & bin} doesn't been created !
And when i create a project with composer, or updating it, i get this result

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> [ErrorException]
>   file_put_contents(C:/Users/KDragon/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-laravel$laravel.json):
>   failed to open stream: Invalid argument
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader]
>   [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies]
>   [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable]
>   [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] []...

Comment: `sudo composer install` ? Oh, I see, you use Windows. open command line terminal "as administrator" and run the command then

Comment: I really did that in the first place, what i can do to solve this problem ?